# Play a sound in loop for remote notifications when app is in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

i try to play a sound in loop when a remote notification arrived when the app is in background.
For foreground i used Media Player and AVFoundation.

I try to execute the method in appFinishLunchingWithOptions but in that moment the user had already clicked the notification in Notification Center and the app is in foreground.

I want the sound play till the user go in Notification Center and click the notification.

Some ideas for that ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

30 seconds is the limit of `UILocalNotication` sound.

There is no way that you can make it repeat. You can schedule it again with time intervals for 30s, but that one will be a schedulation of another alarm.

Apple is strict with its rules, and if you try to add a sound more than 30 seconds, the `UILocalNotifications` will just ignore that sound.

Comment: thanks, but is about remote notification. i imagine there are the same rules, doesn't it?

Comment: thanks, you are right. this is from official Apple documentation:"Custom sounds must be under 30 seconds when played. If a custom sound is over that limit, the default system sound is played instead."

Comment: @dev1001 I kept in mind about Remote Notifications and I typed in LocalNotifications. Anyway the basics are the same thing just different type.